# Can I uncommit myself after a private beta launches?

Tags: discussion, area-51

Can I uncommit myself after a private beta launches?

Comment: That's when you're supposed to be *fulfilling* your commitment...

Comment: I don't have a concrete answer, but judging from http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/60731/how-do-i-uncommit-to-a-stack-exchange I think the answer amounts to "No".

Comment: I'm with Shog.  Private beta's only 7 days, can you not hang until then and fulfill the commitment?

Comment: @Shog9 i know, but the site in question is not turning out the way I thought it would and I think someone would be better able to contribute to it.

Comment: @cbrulak: Ah! Then it's time to sell your valuable Private Beta account on Ebay...

Comment: Code golf, no? Now is the time you *can* make a difference. If you want problems with a metric other than character count, then *pose some.* [I'm open to that](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/67/78) stuff, and [Noah actively agreed with you](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/66/78).

Comment: I am going to agree with Shoggy here.  Doesn't that defeat the purpose of committing to the site? ;)

Answer (score 6):

No, you cannot -- you can only complete the commitment to free it up.

http://area51.stackexchange.com/faq

> Once you've fulfilled your commitment on a new site by asking and answering a few questions, you'll be able to commit to another site. If you are very active, you may be able to re-use your commitment as soon as the second day of public beta. If you aren't active on the site, you won't be able to re-use the commitment until the end of the public beta (up to 90 days).

Comment: A few sites stayed in public beta for more than 90 days. Geographic Information Systems comes to mind, being at its 190th day in beta. What happens then? Is the expiry date the end of public beta or 90 days?