# How can I fulfill my commitment to Japanese.SE on Area 51?

Tags: support, area-51, commitment-fulfillment

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I uncommit from a Stack Exchange proposal?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/60731/how-do-i-uncommit-from-a-stack-exchange-proposal)
>   [How to “follow through” on an area51 proposal](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/103294/how-to-follow-through-on-an-area51-proposal)

I tried to so some searching around and couldn't find a good answer already, so here goes.

Currently I have 300 reputation on the [Japanese.SE](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/) site and my Area 51 commitment is showing that it is still unfulfilled. Since I'm at my maximum number of commitments I'd like to free one up for some of the sites that might be upcoming in the near future; however, the Japanese site is keeping me from doing that. At this point in time my Japanese studies are on the back burner (life is what happens while you are studying :/) and I'm unlikely to be much of a help on the site. Is there a way to free up the commitment so I can use it elsewhere where I may be more of a help?

Comment: The exact details are not public I think, but I know that you need a minimum number of posts. Just post a few more questions or answers, I don't think you're far away from fulfilling the commitment

Comment: Perhaps your question is closer to: can I *cancel* my commitment?

Comment: @Fabian The commitment details are public. 10 questions/answers and three months of participation. :)

Comment: @Anna It seems I'm getting confused about what I'm allowed to tell people and what not ;-)

Comment: @RobZ It's shown when you commit to a site in that pop-up form where you put in your name, expertise level, etc.

Comment: @RobZ I agree. I think Area 51 FAQ can be amended to include that information, but you might want to make a separate request for that on the [Area 51 Discussion site](http://discuss.area51.stackexchange.com/) so that it get missed among the rest of the discussion in this post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fulfilling a commitment doesn't have anything to do with earning reputation although that usually happens as a side-effect of contributing to the site.

To fulfill your commitment, you have to post a combined total of 10 questions and answers and participate for three months, as described in the commitment description:

> I commit to participate actively in [site name] for at least three months, especially during the private beta, and to ask or answer at least ten questions.

There is no way to get out of a commitment except for fulfilling it or waiting till the site graduates from beta.

Comment: @RobZ If it just ages away, it's not much of a commitment, is it? I know it can be inconvenient (I'm stuck in two commitments right now that I'm unlikely to fulfill any time soon), but I think commitments ultimately serve a valuable purpose.

Answer (score 2):

> How can I fulfill my commitment to Japanese.SE on Area 51?

Ask more questions, post more answers.  Even if most of the questions are over your head, you can still seed the site with high quality questions.  Posting answers is more difficult if you aren't an expert, but the site was intended for experts, and you did commit to helping at that level, so...

> Is there a way to free up the commitment so I can use it elsewhere where I may be more of a help?

Not currently, no.

Your only options are

1. Fulfill the Japanese commitment
2. Uncommit from one of your other two commitments which are still in the commit stage